# zipWith is not returning the result

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm trying to execute two queries against the database, the first one inserts the data then I do another query to get some data from a different collection then combine the result, but the zipWith is not being executed.

```
Mono<String> orderMono = orderDtoMono
                .map(EntityDtoUtil::toEntity)
                .flatMap(this.repository::insert)
                .zipWhen(order -> this.clientRepository.findById(order. getOrderId()))
                .map(i -> {
                    System.out.println("here");
                    return i.getT1().getOrderId() +" : "+i.getT2().getSuccessUrl();});
        return orderMono;
```

The insert query works, however, the zipWhen is not executed and I get API result as 200 empty body.

The desired result would be the string created inside map operator at the end.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using right repository? For its weird that you insert into repository and then try to find smth in client repository by OrderId. So you easer should use same repository or in findById(order.getUserId()) would make more sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip will work only when both publishers return some data. Otherwise it will be empty.

In your case, you had just inserted a new record via repository `.flatMap(this.repository::insert)` - then you immediately expect this order id to be present via `this.clientRepository.findById(order. getOrderId())`. I believe it will be empty - so in your case you get empty response.

Do you have any DB trigger to insert records in other tables based on the new order id? Can you explain this - `this.clientRepository.findById(order. getOrderId())` ?

Comment: How does it solve OP problem? its sounds like a questions and not an answer

Comment: Hi, The first 2 statements should give OP an idea how zip works and what could be wrong. The question is the last part if OP still faces an issue and ask him to more info.